# Flutter/Dart How To Convert Image to 1bit per pixel format like this

Tags: flutter, dart, bitmap

Image like this -
[image]

to array like this -

```
const unsigned char epd_bitmap_Group_1 [] PROGMEM = {
0xff, 0xff, 0xff, 0xff, 0xff, 0xff, 0xff, 0xff, 0xff, 0xff, 0xff, 0xff, 0xff, 0xff, 0xff, 0xff, 
0xff, 0xff, 0xff, 0xff, 0xff, 0xff, 0xff, 0xff, 0xff, 0xff, 0xff, 0xff, 0xff, 0xff, 0xff, 0xff};
```

Comment: Does this help? https://iotexpert.com/iot-expert-logo-conversion-bitmap-madness-part-1/

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

What do you mean by 1bit per pixel?
Did you mean 1 byte per pixel?
Or 3 bytes per pixel, to preserve RGB channels?

Edit:

Indeed you meant 1 bit per pixel. I guess the format specify 8 pixels should be packed in single byte, so you will need to use the function `toByteData` referenced [here](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-ui/Image-class.html) with ' format = ImageByteFormat.rawRgba ', make a function to convert rgba color into single bit, then pack every eight pixels into byte, (you will probably need to handle the stride of end of line), then print the result.

Comment: Thank you for the replay I will check it. I have no big idea but I want to convert image like this site - https://javl.github.io/image2cpp/